# how to stop if loop once array has a number

Tags: c, arrays, fibonacci

I need to create a program where user will input a number of integers and the program will output the fibonacci sequence number having the next larger number than the user input.
fibonacci sequence as follows:

```
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765
```

Example:

user inputs: `[1, 9, 22]`
output should be: `2, 13, 34`

I cant seem to make the if loop stop once it has already acquired a value because the output will always display 4181, 4181, 4181.
My code is as follows below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int i, n, a[100];
    int inputarray[3], j;
    int outputarray[3];

    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    for (i = 2; i < 20; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%5d",a[i]);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf ("\nEnter numbers of input array:");
        scanf ("%d", &inputarray[j]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            if (a[j] > inputarray[i])
                outputarray[i] = a[j];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%5d", outputarray[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you say the *if loop*, what exactly is that?

Comment: what is an "if loop"!?

Comment: Also, your code uses an ancient `main()` signature which is no longer acceptable, change it to `int main(void)`.

Comment: Your code style is also very inconsistent, so it looks like you either copied and pasted parts of it from somewhere else or there is more than one programmer writting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `break` statement because once you found required value, you don't have to keep looping for `j`

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  for (j=0; j<20; j++)
  { 
    if(a[j] > inputarray[i])
    {
        outputarray[i] = a[j]; 
        break;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: He have to compare to all Fibonacci numbers, so inner loop is required

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach given the structure of the OP's code.

Comment: Ok, that's better. But now you only wrote 5 lines of code and yet you have inconsistencies in your choice of style and the indentation is terrible!

Comment: @Iharob atleast try to see logic before downvoting, I only corrected broken part of code

Answer (score 1):

I would be much easier if you did not use a `for` loop (because you don't want to iterate over a given amount of values). If your loop depends on a condition use a `do-while`/`while` loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    while (a[j] <= inputarray[i])
    {
        j++;
    }
    outputarray[i] = a[j];
}
```